# How to access properties from a textbox to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a program which sends emails to gmail server. I have completed my goal but now my next goal is to make a login form where I can login with different gmail accounts and send mails.

Here's the code for the `Login` form:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = new User();
    user.Email = textBoxEmail.Text;
    user.Password = textBoxPassword.Text;
}
```

I want my `user.Email` and `user.Password` to be saved in the second form (main form), which is this:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(/*I want user.Email to be here */,"Pavel Valeriu");
    mail.To.Add(textBoxTo.Text);
    mail.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text;
    mail.Body = richText.Text;

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("pavelvaleriu24@gmail.com", /* and user.Password here */);
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

    MessageBox.Show("mail sent");
    Close();
}
```

Comment: this question is not related to `email` tag. I remove it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value from the login form to the main form through the constructor

FormLogin:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User user = new User();
    user.Email = textBoxEmail.Text;
    user.Password = textBoxPassword.Text;
    FormMain frm = new FormMain (textBoxEmail.Text,textBoxPassword.Text);
    frm.show();
}
```

FormMain:

```
public FormMain(string _email,string _password)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Email = _email;
   Password = _password;
}
string Email = sting.Empty;
string Password = string.Empty;

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress(Email ,"Pavel Valeriu");
    mail.To.Add(textBoxTo.Text);
    mail.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text;
    mail.Body = richText.Text;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("pavelvaleriu24@gmail.com", Password );
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    Close();
}
```

**EDIT :-**

Include the default constructor for the Form

```
public FormMain()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, this exactly what i want!

Comment: I made this, but now I have this error "'SendEmail.Form1' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"...

Comment: include the default constructor in the form ,

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `static class UserInformation` with field `static string Username` & `static string Password` and in the first form

```
UserInformation.Username = "Sth";
```

and in second form

```
youTextBox.Text = UserInformation.Username.
```

Please read the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx for more information

Comment: the concept of mail client needs an static class and value like this, because you need the Username and Password anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You could declare User `class` as `public static` on your first from:

```
public static class User...
...
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    User.Email = textBoxEmail.Text;
    User.Password = textBoxPassword.Text;
}
```

and on Main form access the User properties of `Form1`:

```
...
 mail.From =Form1.User.Email
```

Answer (score 0):

If security and design is no big issue and you 'just want it to work', you can go ahead and create a static class that can hold this information for you, like a data provider.

```
public static class LoginDataProvider
{
    public static string Email {get; set;}
    public static string Password {get; set;}
}
```

You can then go ahead and get save the information in your login form:

```
LoginDataProvider.Email = textBoxEmail.Text;
LoginDataProvider.Password = textBoxPassword.Text;
```

You can then go ahead and retrieve the information in the second form the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your appication in ASP.NET you can mention username and password in 'Session' other wise, you are moving with window application you can store credentials in global variables and access it any web forms

Answer (score 0):

When you create the object of main form, when the user is authenticated, create a `constructor` to pass the user's email & password like

```
mainForm(string userEmail, string password) or mainForm(User user)
```

So

```
User user = new User();
user.Email = textBoxEmail.Text;
user.Password = textBoxPassword.Text;

If(user.Authenticate())
{
    //call new MainForm(user)
```